# How to fix `...theme.mixins` unexpected Token SyntaxError?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use material-ui 1.3.1 and reactjs 16.4.1.

I copy and pasted the [PaperSheet Component](https://material-ui.com/demos/paper/) into my application. Now my app is not compiling anymore. Any ideas whats the reason?

```
ERROR in ./src/components/search/PaperSheet.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:/Users/hatieke/Projects/brand-eins/brandeins-prototype/brandeins-prototype-ui/src/components/search/PaperSheet.jsx: Unexpected token (9:4)

   7 | const styles = theme => ({
   8 |   root: {
>  9 |     ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
     |     ^
  10 |     paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  11 |     paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  12 |   },

 @ ./src/components/search/index.js 12:18-41
```

Two questions: Why does material-ui use this destructuring everywhere? and why does it not work with my app?

Comment: They use it because it's a very handy. You need the `transform-object-rest-spread` Babel plugin since it's not in the language yet. You can e.g. use the [stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-3.html) preset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use spread because it's a very handy alternative compared to using e.g. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Since rest/spread is not in the language yet, you need the [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/) Babel plugin in order to use it. You can e.g. use the [stage-3 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-3.html) which includes it.

**.babelrc**

```
"presets": [
  "env",
  "react",
  "stage-3"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update your .babelrc

To use the latest ECMAScript syntax you will need to transpile t back to something readable by the browser.

Find where you have your react preset, either in a .babelrc or in the package.json and add

```
"presets": [
  "stage-2",
  "react"
]
```

To use preset stage 2 you will need to install it via npm/yarn. Also to know what version you need to install please check your package.json and find out if you are using

`babel-core` or `@babel/core`

based on that you should either use `babel-preset-stage-2` or `@babel/preset-stage-2`

After this restart your build process and go again. I would suggest getting a firm grasp on transiplation and the use of babel. you can read about how all of this works in their docs [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc.html)